# Can't Pass Cookie into Hidden Form Field with Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-tag-manager, hidden-field

I have some Javascript or jQuery that I am using to pass information stored in a cookie into a hidden form field on my website.

However, whenever I run a test, the code doesn't work - nothing gets pulled into my hidden field.

Here is the code I am using (I have tried both javascript and jQuery - I'll show the code I've used for both):

```
document.querySelector("input[name='field:7961189']").value = "{{cookie - gclid}}";

$('input[name="field:7961189"]').val('{{cookie - gclid}}').change();
```

I've tried testing this out on my visible form fields by replacing the "name" with the one of my visible fields, like so,

```
document.querySelector("input[name='email']").value = "{{cookie - gclid}}";

$('input[name="phone"]').val('{{cookie - gclid}}').change();
```

and it works - the fields are populated with data from my cookie. But when I try the code at the top of the page, it doesn't work. I am stumped. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Here is the HTML around it.

```
<div class="custom-form" data-form-id="1449777"> 
<h2 class="babel-ignore">UTM Fields</h2> 
<p class="babel-ignore form-description">Disruptive Analytics UTM Fields</p> 
<div class="form-group" data-field-id="7961189"> 
<label for="field:7961189" class="control-label babel-ignore">gclid </label> 
<input type="text" class="text form-control" name="field:7961189" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

then

```
document.querySelector("input[name='field:7961189']").value = getCookie("gclid") // or wathever cookie is named
```

source :
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: I don't think getting the cookie value is the problematic part - Google Tag Manager can pull the values for first party cookies into variables without any custom code. Also the OP mentions that this works on visible form fields, but not on a hidden one.